# Solve coupled differential equation using Matrix

Tags: differential-equations, matrix, linear-algebra

I am a complete beginner to Mathematica. I am trying to solve the following equation:
$\frac{d}{dt}\rho_t = -0.5* \eta* \Gamma[\rho_t]$, where $\Gamma[\rho_t]$ is a 4x4 matrix whose coefficients are given.

I know that in principle I could write down 4x4=16 coupled differential equation, i.e. $\frac{d}{dt}\rho_{11}=-0.5 * \eta * \Gamma[\rho_{11}] = -0.5 * \eta * (2\rho_{11} - \rho_{22} - \rho_{33})$ and then use DSolve to obtain a solution for $\rho_{11}$. However, I wanted to know if there is a way to specify $\rho$ as a matrix, and then write down and solve an equation as I have given at the beginning.

A quick look at the Tutorial didn't yield any results, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I must be missing something. If your `A` Matrix is 4 by 4 (which you call $\Gamma$). Then you have 4 coupled ode's. Not 16. So the dependent variables are 4. Why do you then say you have 16 ode's? Is you system not   `Y' = A* Y` type of system of ode's?

Comment: How about something like this: a = {{4, -6}, {1, -1}};
DSolve[{x1'[t], x2'[t]} == a . {x1[t], x2[t]}, {x1[t], x2[t]}, t]

Comment: @Nasser If my Matrix is 4 by 4, then it has 16 elements, and as such we have 16 equations of the form $\frac{d}{dt} \rho_{ij} = \sum_{i, j} \alpha_{ij} \rho_{ij}$.

Comment: @bills Thanks for the hint, where do the terms {4, -6} come from? Or is this standard, then I will consult the docs.

Comment: I just picked a random a matrix... you need to replace it with your 4 by 4. This is close to an example in the help for DSolve, under the "Scope" and "Systems of Differential Equations".

Comment: @bills I checked the help and I don't yet understand what the x1[t], x2[t] in your example are. As far as I understand, the example on the Help page discusses a solution for a single vector x1, not for my matrix A.

Comment: If you have 16 equations, then vectorize it so you have a 16-vector of equations. Your matrix will then be 16x16 (but mostly zeros). Then use DSolve. As long as its linear, you ought to get a solution. For example: a = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {16, 16}]; DSolve[x'[t] == a . x[t],  x[t] \[Element] Vectors[16], t]